# C# Entity Framework Core, Inner Select in Left Join

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I wanted to make the following SQL Server equivalent using entity framework. The original SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT 
C.CustomerID, 
P.Title,
P.FirstName, 
P.LastName,
SOH.SalesOrderNumber,
SOH.SubTotal, 
SOH.TotalDue, 
SOH.OrderDate, 
SOH.ShipDate,
SOD.UnitPrice, 
SOD.LineTotal
FROM Sales.Customer AS C
INNER JOIN Person.Person AS P ON P.BusinessEntityID = C.PersonID
LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH ON SOH.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
LEFT JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SOD ON SOD.SalesOrderID = SOH.SalesOrderID
WHERE P.FirstName = 'Aaron'
```

This the C# which seem to get close but it doesn't do a nice join instead it does an inner select

```
using (var db = new AdventureWorks2014Context())
{
    var queryable = db.Customer
        .Include(c => c.Person)
        .Include(c => c.SalesOrderHeader)
        .ThenInclude(soh => soh.SalesOrderDetail)
        .Where(x => x.Person.FirstName == name)
        .Select(c => new CustomerOrderDetails
        {
            CustomerId = c.CustomerId, 
            Title = c.Person.Title,
            FirstName = c.Person.FirstName, 
            LastName = c.Person.LastName, 
            SalesOrderHeaderLine = c.SalesOrderHeader.Select(soh => new CustomerSalesOrderHeaderLine
            {
                SubTotal = soh.SubTotal, 
                TotalDue = soh.TotalDue,
                OrderDate = soh.OrderDate,
                ShipDate = soh.ShipDate, 
                SalesOrderLine = soh.SalesOrderDetail.Select(so => new CustomerSalesOrderLine
                {
                    LineTotal = so.LineTotal, 
                    UnitPrice = so.UnitPrice
                })
            })
        });

    return queryable.ToList();
}
```

This is the SQL that the above code produces

```
exec sp_executesql N'
SELECT 
[c].[CustomerID], 
[p].[Title], 
[p].[FirstName], 
[p].[LastName], 
[t].[SubTotal], 
[t].[TotalDue], 
[t].[OrderDate], 
[t].[ShipDate], 
[t].[SalesOrderID], 
[t].[LineTotal], 
[t].[UnitPrice], 
[t].[SalesOrderID0], 
[t].[SalesOrderDetailID]
FROM [Sales].[Customer] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN [Person].[Person] AS [p] ON [c].[PersonID] = [p].[BusinessEntityID]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [s].[SubTotal], [s].[TotalDue], [s].[OrderDate], [s].[ShipDate], [s].[SalesOrderID], [s0].[LineTotal], [s0].[UnitPrice], [s0].[SalesOrderID] AS [SalesOrderID0], [s0].[SalesOrderDetailID], [s].[CustomerID]
    FROM [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] AS [s]
    LEFT JOIN [Sales].[SalesOrderDetail] AS [s0] ON [s].[SalesOrderID] = [s0].[SalesOrderID]
) AS [t] ON [c].[CustomerID] = [t].[CustomerID]
WHERE [p].[FirstName] = @__name_0
ORDER BY [c].[CustomerID], [t].[SalesOrderID], [t].[SalesOrderID0], [t].[SalesOrderDetailID]',N'@__name_0 nvarchar(50)',@__name_0=N'Aaron'
```

It it possible to write the C# so that it just uses a left join, the same as my original query (at the top)? as I don't want the inner select. This is less performant. I don't want the inner select on the sales order header and details. I want it as I wrote the original (At the top). The pure SQL ones read less pages and does less scans.

Please note that I am trying to write it to be as good as a pure SQL query (which I have learnt massive amounts about, thanks to brent ozar's knowledge). I know it will give me what I want, but I want to be able to writer EF that is as close to how I would want the SQL written, as it's no good when your product has millions of rows and is slow because EF has generated a dirty dump of SQL. In the case of this one the Customer scan count has gone up to 56 from 1, and the logical reads have doubled, which is not as good.

Comment: Do you get the desired result with the EF generated query? If so. What's your question. AFAIK is a JOIN just another SELECT with a given WHERE condition.

Comment: "It it possible to write the C# so that it just uses an left join, the same as my original query (at the top)?" I've updated the question at the bottom with that.
It will give me the results I need but is doing more work that it needs to as its now scanning the Customer table for every row and increased logical reads.

Comment: Why won't you run the custom SQL?

Comment: Because we use EF as a base for our projects, but when the products are of age or do get slow I have been writing custom SQL which improves performance. This is primarily learning for me and my teams so we can write better EF as previously we have not been doing so. So I want know If it is possible to do the inner join instead of a select inside it and then joining.

Comment: It is known issue https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17622
They just prioritize Change Tracker instead of query generation. Anyway try to remove Includes, they are redundant and may cause such effect. But I think problem in navigation properties generation.

Comment: Thanks, ok so it is a known issue and may one day be made cleaner. Cheers :) I tried removing the includes but no difference. We have been hit lots in the past with lazy loading (thrashing the database) hence why I added them but yea seems to work the same without!

Comment: You do not need Includes at all if your projection is fully custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after Svyatosalav Danyliv replied, it would seem that it is a limitation of EF Core.

It is known issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17622).

However much I try to adopt EF, it's just not as good as writing the SQL yourself.